# Can I make the LVGL chart display floating point values?

Tags: c, lvgl

I'm trying to follow the widgets_demo example from lvgl demos. All is well besides the fact that chart seems to only display integer values.
Is there a tweak somewhere which allows me to display floating point values or should I just multiply the doubles until they can be represented in ints?

I've tried messing with `lv_chart_set_axis_tick` but no dice, the function only expects short.

For clarity here is a screenshot.
[LVGL chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnY87.png)

Comment: Related? LVGL Forum [How to display a float/int?](https://forum.lvgl.io/t/how-to-display-a-float-int/3098)

Comment: @WeatherVane apologies for misconception, I need to add floating point values to a set rather than formatting a string.